# What to make first while making android apps?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android. I learn the basic concepts one at a time. But now i'm trying to make a slightly large project. How should i approach this? Should I make all the activities first or should i make activities along with code? Or should i just continue on with the anything i like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you would need to think of is what exactly your app does.Once you have that in mind the next thing your're going to want to do is think of an interface for the app which usually leads to deciding what information needs to be shown when and on which screen.Once you know what needs to be where you can start the actual coding,i suggest 1 activity at a time.
If you want a large project i suggest a to-do app.